# Working around missing MI in C#

Tags: c#

I have a some code that gets passed a class derived from a certain class. Let's call this a parameter class.
The code uses reflection to walk the class' members and analyze certain custom attributes given to them. Basically, it's a configurable parser which will analyze input according to the attributes and put what it found into the data members.

This is used in several places in our code. You specify the parameter class, putting in attributed data members, and pass this to the parser. Something like this:

```
public class MyFancyParameters : ParametersBase
{
  [SomeAttribute(Name="blah", AnotherParam=true)]
  public string Blah { get; set; }

  // .. .more such stuff
}

var parameters = new MyFancyParameters();
Parser.Parse(input, parameters);
```

In many places there are similar groups of attributed data members that need to get parsed. So the parameter classes are, in some places, similar. That's redundant and that, of course, hurts. Whenever I need a change in such an area, I need to make that change in half a dozen places, all clones. It's just a matter of time when these parts will start drift apart.

However, the similarities cannot be grouped in acyclic graphs, so I can't use single inheritance to group them.
What I would do in C++ is to put these chunks of similar stuff into their own classes, just inherit a bunch of them that contain whatever I need, and be done. (I think that's referred to as mix-in inheritance.)
C#, however, doesn't have multiple inheritance. So I was thinking of putting these chunks into data members and change the parser to recurse into data members. But that would considerably complicate the parser.

What else is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have your parser accept a collection of parameter classes instead of a single parameter class?  Alternately, you could allow the parser to recurse into your parameter class and have it supply additional parameter classes as properties.  Basically, every property of a ParametersBase derived class that inherits from type ParametersBase is recursed into and flattened into a single list of parameters.

Actually, I just saw that you already mentioned the recursive solution.  I think this is probably your best bet and it's not too complex to support.  You should be able to create a helper function for enumerating the parameter properties that makes a hierarchy look like a flat class.

---

Here's some code that would provided a 'flattened' view of your properties, if I understand your requirement correctly.  You'll probably want to augment the production code with additional safeguards (such as keeping a stack of types to detect circular references.)

```
public class ParametersParser
{
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllParameterProperties(Type parameterType)
    {
        foreach (var property in parameterType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(SomeAttribute)))
                yield return property;

            if (typeof(ParametersBase).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                foreach (var subProperty in GetAllParameterProperties(property.PropertyType))
                    yield return subProperty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the parser to analyze the parameter class recursively to me looks harder than you seem to think, but it's not impossible. However, I was hoping for something else than hacking around a language restriction. Isn't there anything clever I could do with interfaces?

Comment: You could use interfaces for the different parameter 'groups', but you'd still need to change every use of the group when you make a change.  The only advantage to using an interface is that you'd get a compilation error if you forgot to modify one of the groups to match the updated interface, but it also means there's one more place that you have to make a change.

Comment: Reading further, I can see that you'll need to keep track of the object values as well, which does make it more complex than simply 'flattening' the properties list.  That said, I can't think of a better solution.  All of the other work-arounds to emulate MI still require writing boilerplate to forward methods or properties and this repeated boilerplate is exactly what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Yep, I need to store references to the objects, too, in order to assign parsed values to them later. As I said, it's doable, but it's a crutch only needed to work around a missing language feature. I still hope to find a better idea to do this.